# Prove that $\texttt{prefix}(L)$ is regular

Tags: formal-languages, regular-languages

Given that $L = \lbrace 0^n1^n : n \geq 0\rbrace$ is a non-regular context-free language, prove that $\texttt{prefix}(L)$ is regular.

So far I have provided that the grammar to produce this language is:
$S \rightarrow 0S1 \thinspace | \thinspace \epsilon$

Would you go about proving $\texttt{prefix}(L)$ is regular just like you would any language, proving that $\Sigma^\star$ = $\texttt{prefix}(L)$, or by induction on the length of the words in $\texttt{prefix}(L)$.

Comment: Can you provide exact definition of $prefix(L)$? Because as per my interpretation that is not regular.

Comment: $\texttt{prefix}(L)$ contains all prefix words in $L$, where a prefix of a word $w$ is a string $x$ such that $w = xy$ for some $y \in \Sigma^\star$. If it is the case for the language given that $\texttt{prefix}(L)$ is not regular, how would you go about proving that then?

Comment: Duplicate: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3442894/prove-that-textttprefixl-is-regular

Comment: How to prove it? About the same as for L itself.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It appears that $prefix(L)$ is non-regular.

Let $L = \{0^n 1^n: n \ge 0\}$.  Then, $prefix(L)$, defined to be the set of all prefixes of strings in $L$, is the set of all strings that consist of zero or more $0$'s followed by at most the same number of $1$'s, i.e. $prefix(L) = \{0^n 1^m: m \le n\}$. Intuitively, the reason $prefix(L)$ is nonregular is that a machine that can check whether the number of $1$'s does not exceed the number of $0$'s must store a count of the number of $0$'s in the input seen so far, and so this language cannot be recognized by a machine with a finite number of states.

A formal proof that $L' := prefix(L)$ is nonregular is as follows.  Consider the subset $S = \{0^1, 0^2, \ldots, 0^p\}$.  Any DFA $M$ that recognizes $L'$ must take the inputs $0^i$ and $0^j$ $(i < j)$ to different states because $0^i 1^j \notin L'$ but $0^j 1^j \in L'$.  Hence, the machine $M$ contains at least $p$ states.  But $p$ was arbitrary. This proves there does not exist a DFA (with a finite number of states) recognizing $L'$.

This proof method requires us to find an infinite subset $S$ of pairwise distinguishable prefixes; see online about the Myhill-Nerode theorem.

Comment: In your formal proof section, did you mean to say "$L'$ must take inputs $0^i$ and $0^j$ $(i < j)$" or did you mean to have "$L'$ must take inputs $0^i$ and $1^j$ $(i > j)$" since that is the definition for the language of $prefix(L)$?

Comment: @RyanGomez I meant $0^j$. These are just prefixes of strings in the language.  Different prefixes in S must take the machine to different states because concatenating them with the same suffix $1^j$ leads in one case to acceptance and in the others case to non-acceptance of input.

Answer (score 0):

The language $\textrm{prefix}(L) = \{0^n1^m:n \geq m\}$. It's not regular.

From the [pumping lemma](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pumping_lemma_for_regular_languages#Use_of_the_lemma):

> Let $L$ be a regular language. Then there exists an integer $p \geq 1$ depending only on $L$, such that every string $w \in L$, of length at least $|w| \geq p$ ( $p$ is called the "pumping length") can be written as $w = x \cdot y \cdot z$(i.e., $w$ can be divided into three substrings), satisfying the following conditions:
>
> - $|y| \geq 1$
> - $|xy| \leq p$
> - $\forall n \geq 0 : xy^nz \in L$

Let's create a word $0^p1^p$. Since $|xy| \leq p$, than the substring of $w$, that we will be pumping has to be wholly within first $p$ characters, meaning that it can consist only of $0$-es.

However, $w = xy^0z \notin L$, since it would contain less $0$-es than $1$-s